# Windows 7 Sidebar Gadget, not getting result for an Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows-desktop-gadgets

In my windows gadget code in made an ajax (POST) call using jQuery in SettingsClosing(event). I watch the ajax call execution through [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Ajax call is returning the desired results.But it is not triggering success callback ajax. I tried the same code in OnPageLoad() event of main view it is working fine there, My code is like this

```
function Login(username, password) {
    var url = "http://example.com/Auth.php";
    var data = { pusername: username, ppassword: password };
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST"
            , dataType: "json"
            , url: url, data: data
            , success: function (refresh_token) {
                System.Gadget.Settings.write("success", "true");
                System.Gadget.Settings.write("dd", refresh_token);
                var tok = refresh_token['refreshtoken'];
                var name = refresh_token['name'];
                System.Gadget.Settings.write("name", name);
                System.Gadget.Settings.write("refreshtoken", tok);

            }
                , error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    System.Gadget.Settings.write("login_error", errorThrown);
                    System.Gadget.Settings.write("login_STATUS", textStatus);
                }
    });
}

function SettingsClosing(event) 
{
    //use this question to now if setting was closed with OK button
    if (event.closeAction == event.Action.commit)
    {
        var username = $('#txtpUsername').val();
        var password = $('#txtpPassword').val();
        Login(username, password);

    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the ajax call is asynchronous, it would seem likely that the code doesn't have the opportunity to run before the operation completes. You could try setting `event.cancel` to true, and then triggering the close manually after your ajax call completes. MSDN reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723677(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you Steven for your help.Would you help me once more, how to trigger the close manually?